# Spring Data Joda Time Duration Type store in mongoDB

Tags: spring-data, jodatime, duration

I have a duration container which looks like this and I also can store this container in my MongoDB with no problem. But if I read the object from database, I get the following exception:

> org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate org.joda.time.Duration using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments 
>       at org.springframework.data.convert.ReflectionEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ReflectionEntityInstantiator.java:64)
>       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:249)
>       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:230)

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong or how I can solve this issue?

```
public class ScheduleDurationContainer {

@JsonView(RestServiceResponseView.SchedulerPublic.class)
private Duration duration;
...

public ScheduleDurationContainer() {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to me your error is due to the fact that Joda Time's Duration does not have a default, no-arg constructor. You need to write a Mongo read converter for Duration. Spring has several examples [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.8.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#mongo.custom-converters)